# Wish & Hope & "have"

Tags: grammar, wish

I'm learning English with "English Grammar in Use. 2012 4-ed. by Murphy R." book and I'm confused with an explanation in Unit 41 "Wish".

It's said there that it's ok to say

> "I **wish** you a **pleasant stay** here."

or

> "I **hope** you **have** a pleasant stay here."

but not

> "I wish you <strike>have</strike> a pleasant stay here."
>
> "I wish you <strike>would have</strike> a pleasant stay here."

So, the question is why I cannot say

> "I **wish** you **had** a pleasant stay here."

?

I guess it's also correct but just is missed in the examples. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > To wish people a pleasant stay

is a hope that hosts typically express when guests/clients arrive. It's what you expect to hear from a receptionist when you check into a hotel. It looks ahead.

When the guests come to settle the bill at the end of their stay, the receptionist may well say:

> > I hope you had a pleasant stay

This looks back on the period when the guests were staying at the hotel.

It's wrong to say:

> > I wish you had a pleasant stay

because it confuses the future and the past - and it's not idiomatic.

It's possible to write:

> > I wish you had better manners

but it's never idiomatic to write:

> > I wish you have (anything)

Instead, you would say:

> > I hope you have/had

Comment: Thank you, Ronald, but it's difficult for me to understand why I can't say "I wish you had a pleasant stay", but can say "I wish you had a car.".  What does it really means "because it confuses the future and the past"?

Comment: Or maybe there is nothing to understand and I just have to remember it as is?

Comment: I guess I've just understood that if I want to wish someone "a thing to have" I can say "I wish you had that thing (car, better manners, etc)" but if I want to wish someone "something" (like a being in some state or condition like 'a good day', 'luck', 'pleasant stay', etc) I can't use "have/had" with "wish". Is it close to the truth?

Comment: @Sergey *I wish you had....* is fine when it means *It would be nice if you possessed....* whether a car, better manners, a fortune or whatever.  Also common is: *I wish you were/had been here/with me*. But you can never use: *I wish you have...*  It is not grammatical.  It's: *I hope you have.....*.

Answer (score 0):

> "I wish you had a pleasant stay here"

means I know you are not having a pleasant stay here right now, but I wish it were not so.

> "I wish for you to have a pleasant stay here"

would be the full version or, in the present subjunctive, "I wish you have a pleasant stay here", which is archaic in style.  You could rewrite it to say, "It is my wish that you have a pleasant stay", which uses the present subjunctive and is not archaic.

> "I hope you have a pleasant stay here"

should take the present subjunctive as well, but it's not used in Modern English like that.  Nowadays, "hope" almost always takes the present indicative:

> "I hope he has a pleasant stay."

(Modern English)

> "I hope that he have a pleasant stay."

(Shakespearean English)

HOWEVER:

> "I pray that he have a pleasant stay here."

(Modern English)

> "Wherefore, the defendant prays this court be moved to grant this
>   motion."

(Opening of Modern English "wherefore" clause in legal briefs and motions)

Shakespeare often used a present subjunctive verb when using the verb "hope", but that is almost never the case today.  This is the reason why your grammar book is having a problem showing you this example and comparing it to "wish" but with no "verb".  It's because "wish" still takes a subjunctive in Modern English (although never in the present subjunctive when "wish" is a verb), whereas "hope" does not take a subjunctive in "Modern English".